# Dragging to empty layout with Vaadin's DragDropLayouts add-on?

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin, add-on

I'm working on a Vaadin project with two Drag and Drop layouts in which the user can drag components from one layout to another. While I got this to work using the DragDropLayouts add-on, I can't drag any components to an empty DragDropLayout.

Is it possible to make it possible to add components to a DDLayout regardless of the number of components in it?

Comment: Make sure the drop target has some minimal height&width, otherwise you can't drop items over a 0x0 pixel area...

Comment: That worked, I never would've thought of checking the layout's size. Thanks for the help.